# How to write a serializer to pass SVG files via DRF API using drf_extra_fields

Tags: django, svg, django-rest-framework, base64

I'm trying to make a serializer to pass an SVG file between an API and a client.

models.py:

```
class Event(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=256, verbose_name='Название')
    cover = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True, upload_to='events/images/', verbose_name='Баннер')
    category = models.ForeignKey('Category', blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, verbose_name='Категория')
    tags = models.ManyToManyField('Tag', verbose_name='Тэги')
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Описание')
    age_limit = models.IntegerField(default=0, verbose_name='Возрастное орграничение')
    artists = models.ManyToManyField(Artist, blank=True, related_name='events_artist', verbose_name='Артисты')
    platform = models.ForeignKey('Platform', blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, verbose_name='Площадка')
    video = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Ссылка на видео')
    price = models.IntegerField(default=0, verbose_name='Цена')
    total_tickets = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Всего билетов')
    tickets = models.ManyToManyField(CustomUser, blank=True, related_name='events_user', verbose_name='Билеты')
    open = models.BooleanField(default=True, verbose_name='Событие открыто')
    comments = models.ManyToManyField('Comment', blank=True, related_name='events_comment', verbose_name='Комментарии')
    when = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Дата и время')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Событие'
        verbose_name_plural = 'События'
```

serializers.py:

```
class EventSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    cover = Base64ImageField(represent_in_base64=True, required=False)
    category = CategorySerializer(required=False)
    tags = TagSerializer(many=True, required=False)
    artists = ArtistSerializer(many=True, required=False)
    platform = PlatformSerializer(required=False)
    comments = CommentSerializer(many=True, required=False)
    tickets = CustomUserSerializer(many=True, required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Event
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'cover', 'category', 'tags', 'description', 'age_limit', 'artists', 'platform', 
                  'video', 'price', 'total_tickets', 'tickets', 'open', 'when', 'comments')
```

But when I try to POST a cover with an SVG image converted to BASE64, I get the error {"cover":["Please upload a valid image."]}. Please tell me how to implement what I need?

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44199817/3001920) @Hallteon, it might be what you need here.